# exiftool creates unwanted directory

Tags: exiftool

I am trying to sort a large media collection with this command:

```
exiftool -v3 -r -d sorted2check/byYear/%Y/%Y-%m/%Y%m%d_%H%M%S%%-c.%%e "-directory<filemodifydate" "-directory<createdate" "-directory<datetimeoriginal" '-FileName<CreateDate' 2BeSorted/
```

Unfortunately, the names are generated like this:

/home/michael/data/ImagesSorted/byYear/2023/2023-06/20230625_142904.mp4/018.mp4

I want to have

```
/home/michael/data/ImagesSorted/byYear/2023/2023-06/018.mp4/018.mp4
```

but I do not see the issue in my pattern. Any quick advice?
Thx

Answer (score 2):

What is the original name of the file?  Your first output seems to indicate that the original file name is "20230625_142904.mp4".

Breaking down your [`-d` (`-dateFormat`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#d-FMT--dateFormat) and assuming the embedded time stamp is "2023:06:25 14:29:04" you are

- First creating a directory called `sorted2check` in the current
  directory.
- Then a directory below that called `byYear` resulting in `sorted2check\byYear`
- Then a directory based upon the year, `sorted2check\byYear\2023`
- Then Year-Month, `sorted2check\byYear\2023\2023-06`
- Then you are creating a directory based upon YearMonthDay_HourMinuteSecond(copy number if needed).Extension.  Which results in a path of `sorted2check/byYear/2023/2023-06/20230625_142904.mp4`

Remember, your date format string applies to **all** date tags.  And you are copying the date tags into both `Directory` and `Filename`.  And that makes things tricky as to which one will contain the actual target directory.

[Example #11](https://exiftool.org/filename.html#ex11) on the Writing "FileName" and "Directory" tags page lists how the target directory is created:

> The output directory is taken from the first directory specified from
> the following list: 1) the Directory tag, 2) the directory part of the
> FileName tag…

So, writing to `Directory` will create a directory path based upon the above result string of `sorted2check/byYear/2023/2023-06/20230625_142904.mp4/`.  Note that because you are writing to the `Directory` tag, `20230625_142904.mp4` is a directory, not a filename.

The final part of your command is to rename the filename based upon the date format string.  This would normally create a file path and name of `sorted2check/byYear/2023/2023-06/20230625_142904.mp4`, with `20230625_142904.mp4` being the name of the file.  Because of the priority listed in Example #11, the directory part is stripped away, leaving only the filename of `20230625_142904.mp4`.

Combining the path written by the `Directory` tag and the filename written by the `Filename` tag, you end up with

```
/sorted2check/byYear/2023/2023-06/20230625_142904.mp4/20230625_142904.mp4
```

I do not know how you get a filename of `018.mp4`, as nothing in the data you provided shows where it would come from.  Unless it is the 18th copy of a file in the target directory.  Be even that falls apart because of the leading 0 in the filename, which would require a copy string of `%%3c`, and the dash in your copy % variable of `%%-c`, which would result in a copy of `-18.mp4`. See the "Advanced features" section of the [`-w` (`-TextOut`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#w-EXT-or-FMT--textOut).

Comment: My advice is when you want to change directory and filename, just copy to the `Filename` pseudo-tag.  You can include the destination directory as part of the date string or as part of the tag copy.  Using both just creates confusion.